# Doubt on time invariant system

Tags: fourier-transform, electrical-engineering, signal-processing

1. Now I am delaying the output of a system (which takes $x \left( t \right)$ as input and gives $t \cdot x \left( t \right)$ as output) by $T$ then final output is:

Let's denote the output of the system, $t \cdot x \left( t \right)$, as $y_{1} \left( t \right)$. So, we have:

$$ y_{1} \left( t \right) = t \cdot x \left( t \right) \tag{1} \label{1}$$

Now, if you want to delay this output by a time delay $T$, the output of the delayed system, $y_{2} \left( t \right)$, will be:

$$ y_{2} \left( t \right) = y_{1} \left( t - T \right) = \left( t - T \right) \cdot x \left( t - T \right) \tag{2} \label{2} $$

So, the output of the system with the delayed output is given by $\left( t - T \right) \cdot x \left( t - T \right)$. This represents the original output, but it has been delayed by a time delay of $T$ units.

(2)I am first delaying the $x \left( t \right)$ by $T$ and giving it as input to the above system then what is the final output?

- Delayed Input: Delay the input signal $x \left( t \right)$ by $T$ to obtain $x \left( t - T \right)$.
- Apply delayed input to the system: Feed the delayed input $x \left( t - T \right)$ into the system with the output equation $y_{1} \left( t \right) = t \cdot x \left( t \right)$.
- Calculate the Output: To find the final output $y_{2} \left( t \right)$, you need to evaluate $y_{1} \left( t \right)$ at $t - T$, as the system output is $y_{1} \left( t - T \right)$. So, substitute $t - T$ for $t$ in the expression for $y_{1} \left( t \right)$:

$$ y_{2} \left( t \right) = \left( t - T \right) \cdot x \left( t - T \right) \tag{3} \label{3}$$

From the above statements I can conclude the system is time invariant. But it is not true $y \left( t \right) = t \cdot x \left( t \right)$ is a time-varying system.

Where did I make the mistake?

I want to know why we use these steps (algorithm) to find the time invariance in the first place. What is the relation between this algorithm and the definition of time invariance?

Please give a clear explanation and explain why the system, which takes input $x \left( t \right)$ and gives output $x \left( a t \right)$, where $a$ is constant, is time-varying after explaining the above question.

Answer (score 1):

An operator, a system,  $\mathcal L$ represented by multiplication with a time function, $\ell (t)$, for example, $\ell(t)=t$, is *not* time invariant. To see this, recall the definition of time invariance.

The operator $\mathcal L$ is called time invariant if for $y(t)=\mathcal L [x(t)]$ and for any $T$: $y(t-T)=\mathcal L [x(t-T)]$. Less formally, the operator $\mathcal L$ may depend on $x$ explicitly but on the time variable may only depend implicitly through $x$.

But writing $y(t)=\ell(t) x(t)$ you do get $y(t-T)=\ell(t-T)x(t-T)$ that is not by the definition of being time variant represented by the multiplier $\ell(t)$. Were it time invariant only the input is delayed not the operator, that is, $y(t-T) = \ell(t)x(t-T)$, which is not the case here.

Regarding time scaling, $x(at)$, it is a time variant operation exactly because of its explicit time dependence that can be seen when writing $x(a(t-T)) = x(at-aT)$ in which the output is delayed not by $T$ but by $aT$.

Comment: but in lot books I read that x(at) is time variant 
and if it is possible can you explain your answer clearly I don't understood what is implicitly and explicitly  .

Comment: an example for an operator that is only implicitly time dependent $\mathcal L:= x \mapsto \sin^2(x)$, it depends on time only through $x=x(t)$ and therefore it is *time invariant*. Contrast this with another operator $\mathcal M:= x \mapsto \sin^2(x+\sqrt{t})$ it depends both on $x$ and on $t$ explicitly.

Comment: how does this is true "A system is considered time-invariant if its output remains the same when the input is shifted or delayed in time. In other words, if you apply a time shift to the input, the output should experience the same shift without any other changes" and how does it is related to the time invariant definition and define the signal clearly because I dont know exact definition of signal and can you clearly explain what is implicit and explicit

Comment: in the definition you quoted only the system input is to be shifted in time, that is in your example, when $\mathcal M =t$, $\mathcal M[x]= tx(t)$, shifting in time the input only *should* be $tx(t-T)$, but that is not $y(t-T)$ if $y(t)=tx(t)$

Comment: yes now I think i understood what is explicit, dependence on time is irrespective of shift time remains as it when it is explicit   ,and can I understand definition of time invariance like "this I am taking a system I am giving x(t) as input it gives tx(t) as a output at time t, now I am give past input or delayed signal as my input (x(t-T))at the same time t ,then the output will be t x(t-T) because outside t only dependence on present time", am I correct ,I this is what your are trying to explain interms of implicit and explicit dependence

Comment: from this explanation I thought" system which takes x(t) as input and gives x(at) as output "   is time invariant but it is variate how how Howwwwwww?

Comment: you are right in both comments and I have fixed my answer above accordingly.

Comment: if it were time invariant then the output should be $y(t-T)$ for an input $x(t-T)$ but instead it is $y(t-aT)$, the two are different if $a \ne 1$.

Comment: can you explain this

let consider system which takes input x(t) and gives x(at) as output 
now I am giving delayed input  by T at time t which is x(t-T) then the output is x(a(t-T))
now I am giving x(t) as input at time t then output is x(at)
let y_1(t)=x(at)
now I am delaying y_1 (t) by T 
after delaying it will become y_1(t-T) which is nothing but x(a(t-T))
from this can I conclude that this time invariant system , I know it is time variant but  where did I done the mistake 
and tell me how to tell whether the  time is explicit or implicit ?

Comment: does the system operator depend on $x$ only in which case the dependence is implicit or it depends also on $t$ besides depending on $x$. For the operator $( \cdot )^2$, that is $x^2$, we only need to know what $x$ is, but for the $x(at)$ we need to know what $t$ is also.

Comment: i dont get it,what do you mean system  operator